# How to avoid precompiled assets being served in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I prefer *not* to concatenate JavaScript files in development mode, but serve them as individual files. So I configured:

development.rb:

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

In my /app/assets/javascript directory I have:

- reviews.js
- reviews/

  - foo.js
  - bar.js

reviews.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree ./reviews
```

I include the JavaScript using `<%= javascript_include_tag "reviews" %>` in my layout. The generated page correctly references the three scripts individually and `reviews.js` is essentially empty. So far so good.

Now when I precompile my assets for production using `rake assets:precompile` the three JavaScript files are concatenated into `reviews.js`. This is all fine for production but now, *in development mode*, the concatenated `reviews.js` is served **in addition** to the two individual files.

Of course, this leads to all kinds of nasty bugs when developing because now, the content of `foo.js` and `bar.js` is served twice, one of them in a potentially older version in `reviews.js`.

How can I make sure Rails doesn't use the precompiled assets in development mode?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It sounds like you are precompiling locally. Because the files exist in the expected location they are being served by your dev server, and the requests are not going to Sprockets.

The only way to stop this is delete the compiled files.

Normally you do not need to compile locally. It is expected that in almost all cases the precompile task will be run during deployment of the app. There is a Capistrano recipe for this on the asset pipeline guide page.

If you do need to have those files locally committed to your repo you could use a branch to avoid the problem. Reserve your master branch for production code, and make a second branch for dev. Only compile and commit assets on master. When you switch to dev, they will be gone. Merge dev into master as required.

Edit: Make sure you force your browser to update (control + F5) or you may find the old assets used from the browser cache!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I deleted the compiled files locally and configured to have them compiled on git push to heroku.

Comment: That was the answer I needed. It's true I don't need these precompiled assets locallywhilst I am developing, but as I'm learning how to configure the asset pipeline, I actually DO need them to test my production mode locally, rather than wait for the surprise on Heroku! For now I'll change the directory name (or put them onto a git branch), but still it's a shame it's one more thing I need to think about, rather than a config option in development env to say "ignore the public/assets directory" which I was hoping for.

Comment: You might have to don't forget to clear your browser cache too so the browser doesn't use the application.js you accidentally loaded before you rm -rf'd public/assets

Comment: Good point, I will edit that answer so that is clear up-front.

Answer (score 83):

In `config/environments/development.rb` set:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/assets_dev"
```

so that in *development* mode Rails will look there (but it will not find anything, as you will not compile assets in development (this is indeed what you are trying to do -- not compile assets)).

When precompiling for *production*, use

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

so it compiles into the default assets folder, `public/assets`.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.  Good find.

Comment: It should be noted that this change will alter the "assets/" path that Rails uses in its URLs, so that you get images like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets_dev/favicon.ico`

Comment: Sometimes you have to precompile assets. So this is the best answer. Otherwise you would need to keep deleting and regenerating assets.

Comment: This just bit me in the test environment:  Selenium was using precompiled assets and my Ajax tests were failing.  I'm going to try this workaround in `config\environments\test.rb`.

Comment: Looks like this no longer works as of Rails 4. It seems to use `config.assets.prefix` for both the directory to precompile files to and the directory to pull assets from.

Comment: In Rails 5.1.6 this won't work if there's `public/assets/` dir present. Server will search for `assets/assets_dev/` and because it will not find a thing the browser will log 404s. If you want to trick the server into serving uncompiled assets, you can rename the `public/assets/` to eg. `public/assets2` or anything. Afaik, the `assets/` dir isn't configurable. Don't forget to restart the server after the rename.

Answer (score 17):

in `config/environments/development.rb` set:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

and no files from `/public` will be served

Comment: bear in mind that any uploaded files in the public folder won't be served so it's probably best to avoid this.

Comment: In latter version this has been changed to `config.serve_static_files`

Comment: In Rails 5.1.6 this will turn off serving assets from the `public/` but it still won't turn on serving assets from `app/assets/` – simply no assets will be served.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked. `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

I observed that the new version of assets pipeline does this when you run `rake assets:precompile` does `rake assets:precompile:all`