# rails 3.1 asset pipeline css caching in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sass

I'm a bit confused as it seems like the application.css is including itself twice, once when it lists the resources from the manifest and then a cache of that.   So when I delete an individual file it still seems to stay alive inside the application.css file.

## application.css (source)

```
/*
*= require twitter/bootstrap
*= require_self
*= require_tree ./common
*= require_tree ./helpers
*/
```

Which works as expected and outputs in dev mode all the relevant individual files

## development.rb

```
  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
```

## output

```
<link href="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/common/announcement.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/common/button.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<Blah blah>
```

## application.css (output)

This should be blank?  Since all I have in my application.css file is the manifest and no actual css but instead i get all my concatenated code 106kb long.

IE if I remove a file in the common directory, it doesn't go away.  It is no longer listed in the output but the css still appears from the application.css

Comment: I have exactly the same problem both with css and js.. cannot figure it out. The "answers" below do not address the issue.  I'm only working in dev mode now. How to turn off the concatonation and minifying? It's causing my jquery plugins to run twice, the CSS is doubled up.

Comment: In config/environments/development.rb, if I set config.assets.debug = false, then the double loads won't occur because the extra javascript/stylesheet tags are not being generated. I don't know if changes, however, are dynamically being made to the consolidated files.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this @holden? I am have the same issues and am trying desperately to figure it out.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had a problem like this before.  It was caused after I had precompiled the assets it was going after the applcation.css inside the public folder as well as in the apps directory.  I'm not sure how to fix it so that it doesn't keep happening while in dev mode but if you delete your `/public/assets` directory it should fix it.

Check and see if you have a public/assets folder, if you do and it's full, it's probably why you're seeing double.

Comment: how am I supposed to hide the assets in the public folder between pushing changes in production and then going back to development?  Can I remove it from my path in dev somehow?

Comment: I deleted my `application.js` and `application.css` but left the fingerprinted versions.  Looks like it's working for me.

Comment: Deleting my application.css and apllication.css.gz fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I am really surprised that this work around solution is needed.  I compile around 10-15 files, and each of those files is now being served as compressed and uncompressed in dev causing havoc.  Does this mean I have to write a script to clean up application.js, application.css, and all the other compressed files each time?  This really does not make much sense.

Comment: If you deploy using Capistrano, you can set up a shared folder for your assets on the production server or a hook to precompile assets on production after each deployment. This way you never have to precompile assets locally and can keep `public/assets` clean on your local machine to avoid the redundant includes. I'm not pretending this is ideal - it's bothersome to me that any jury rigging is needed with the assets pipeline - just that it's a relatively clean workaround.

Comment: Deleting the /public/assets directory fixed a bunch of weird issues for me with active_admin on the front-end. Thanks!

Comment: I bet this is happening if you cancel a deploy partway through — assets get compiled, but never cleaned.

Comment: i may not be understanding things fully, but I deploy to Heroku and precompile my assets locally, then push to heroku using git. although deleting `public\assets` could fix issue in development, wouldn't you need to re-compile before deploying to Heroku again? and, check all the files into git again? Perhaps i'm not fully understanding?

Answer (score 38):

There is currently (2012-09-24) a bug in rails/sprockets causing it to not properly detect imported files.

This should be fixed in rails 3.2.9 and later but in the mean time, you can work around it as follows:

1. Kill the rails instance
2. rm -rf tmp/cache
3. Start the rails instance

You should now be seeing the correct css.

Comment: Peter, can you please provide a link to this bug?

Comment: just wanted to note that this was exactly what i needed to do. clearing the cache after setting the switch in development.rb did the trick

Comment: I had rails running while I made gem changes, which led `twitter-bootstrap-rails` to have stale css. Destroyed the folder, all fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Also refresh browser cache by CTRL+F5 (Cmd+Shift+R on Mac)

Answer (score 10):

You might want to look at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854902/686460

"Adding config.serve_static_assets = false to development.rb will prevent loading files from /public/assets"

That did it for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately, it's still serving a compressed version of application.js directly from /public/assets

Comment: Oops, sorry @Agustin, this solution did work.  However, all assets that were not part of the Asset pipeline are no longer served (such as favicon.ico and fonts).  Looks like I'll have to come up with a solution for those assets.

Comment: This answer suggests another approach:  assign a dummy asset folder for the development environment.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11587288/550712

Comment: Restart the server afterwards

Answer (score 7):

@Agustin's solution does it for me but here are a few things you need to do:

1. Delete everything in /tmp/cache/assets
2. Add `config.serve_static_assets = false` to development.rb or test.rb (credits to @Agustin)
3. Restart your server.
4. Make sure your application.js / .css is not cached in your browser. Go to `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js?body=1` and hit ctrl+f5 to force refresh (you can also try appending appending a randomizer param at the end: `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js?body=1&rnd=12343`
   If you get something else and ctrl+f5 still hasn't helped, you need to clear your browser's cache.

Skipping either of these steps returned a cached application.js / .css conflicting with my updates in single files.

Comment: god this is annoying... no luck here yet

Comment: is there anything cached in public? inspect the page and make sure application.css is not being served twice (or contains code)... I know how you're feeling, it's very annoying.

Answer (score 4):

The best way, that worked for me is to delete content of *tmp/cache/** directory...

Answer (score 3):

The thing that worked for us was setting 'config.assets.debug = false'

This no longer set the HTML included CSS as href="/assets/bootstrap-new.css?body=1", instead set it up as href="/assets/bootstrap-new.css", which I think was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Despite clearing tmp/cache and public/assets the minified application.css was still cached and served up from somewhere and my changes to individual css files were not getting served.

This worked for me:
in application.css remove the line `*= require_self`

restart server

that seems to remove the cache and if you click on application.css in your browser source you will no longer see the minified version

replace the `*= require_self` back into the file and continue developing.

Answer (score 0):

There was one last step required for me, but I got it fixed.  Here's what I did:

1. shut down the rails server
2. rake assets:clean
3. rake tmp:clear
4. restart the rails server

Then, I refreshed my screen in Google Chrome, and IT STILL DID NOT WORK.  So, I launched Firefox and voila, it was actually working.  This means that Chrome was caching the old files within the browser.  So, I then cleared out the browser cache in Chrome, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but one fix that worked for me is that I had nginx proxying to my development environment and it had a `location ~ ^/(assets)/` block in the configuration. Either comment it out, or try restarting nginx to invalidate the cache. If you're developing, you'll likely just want to comment it out entirely.

I lost way too much time troubleshooting this until I remembered that.

Answer (score -5):

The assets do their job better when running the app in production environment then you'll have loading only the application.css with all the files included, and compressed, there to reduce the server request and this application.css with the compressed styles will be cached.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html