# Issues with Rails 3.2 application.css.scss caching in development

Tags: caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, stylesheet, asset-pipeline

I seem to be having major issues with the asset pipeline in Rails 3.2. It alls started because I wanted to add a single, simple style to my application.css.scss whilst working in the development environment. I have done this in the past with no problem and it just works because there is no caching occurring (as you would expect).

However, when I attempted to add the new style today, Rails refused to load the updated styles. I checked my environment settings and they all seem correct in development.rb,

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

I did some research and came across [rails 3.1 asset pipeline css caching in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158987). Following the advice given in that question, I made sure that I deleted the `tmp/cache` folder as well performed a clean using `rake assets:clean` just in case I had run the app in production mode at some point and it needed cleaning up.

After all this, still no luck. Just to confirm that I hadn't made a bonehead mistake, I temporarily moved the style to another stylesheet. No problems! It worked perfectly! So I moved the style back and it won't load again.

I also checked the console. It reloaded the other stylesheet correctly but no mention of the original stylesheet.

Now, here comes the major issue. As a last ditch effort, I tried clearing my browser cache. I normally have no problems with it on but I thought something might be cached and causing problems. I cleared it and reloaded the app and.... no styles loaded whatsoever!

It seems that all of my application.css.scss styles were cached at some previous point and now I simply can't reload them!

### UPDATE:

Although I still haven't fixed the problem, I've worked around it by creating a new stylesheet called main.css.scss (name not important) and moving all of the styles to the new stylesheet. This works because of the `//= require_tree .` directive in the manifest.

But if anyone can shed some light on why the original stylesheet stopped working, I would love to know!

Answer (score 0):

try `rm -r public/assets/*`

maybe your assets:clean task is not working properly.