# Rails 3.2 asset pipeline including both *.js files and application.js in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We have an older Rails 3.2 app that is using the Asset pipeline. It is now including both the original js files from app/assets AND an application.js. Ideally, we'd like to remove the application.js from the page in development. Is there a config variable to have the uncompressed, un-minified JavaScript files from app/assets only?

The layout application.html.erb is

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Did you `rake assets:precompile` in development? What does your config look like? The default development config should serve just the unminified asset files

Comment: I think I did run `rake assets:precompile` and that might be causing the problem. Is there a way to undo that? I've also deleted public/assets via `rm -rf public/assets` but this didn't seem to affect it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid precompiled assets being served in development mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013478/how-to-avoid-precompiled-assets-being-served-in-development-mode)